# Ruby on rails 3 rendering JSON data

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

I'm trying to render my object as JSON but the when I try to access it in the view using ExtJS, I'm not getting any value for it, it is undefined. I need to send the **success** attribute in the response.
Here's my code:
Render in controller:

**render(:text=>"{success: true,userdata: #{admin.to_json}}")** where **admin** is my model object.

In the view, I've the following handler function written in ExtJS:

success :

```
     function(form,action){
                Ext.SM.set("uname",action.result.userdata.fname + ' ' + action.result.userdata.lname);
                NWST.init();}
```

I'm not getting any value for **fname** and **lname**.
Could some1 plz help me with this...

Comment: Have you tried changing `render :text => ...` to `render :json => ...` to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

add :success=>true to @admin first, then render :json=>@admin

Comment: @admin[:success] = true    @neeraj: please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask to learn how to use Stackoverflow